# What is a Plot Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Plot Word™**.
Use the following examples to find the rule.

[image]

In case you want it as a CSV:

```
Plot Words™, Not Plot Words™
fox, wolf
may, june
wall, walk
pork, ham
beef, cow
cage, coop
spoon, fork
cull, call
gun, knife
face, mind
hedge, shrub
room, house
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Plot Word™ or not on its own.

These are not the only examples of Plot Words™, many more exist.

Hint 1

> The original name for this puzzle was What is a Graph Word™?

Hint 2

> y=mx+b

Hint 3

> 1 is 01, 2 is 02, 3 is 03 and so on.

Comment: In the CSV version it says "face, LOL/FLIRT, mind" instead of just "face, mind" in the table, is that intentional?

Comment: is LOL FLIRT in the CSV part of the puzzle?

Comment: The links in the first paragraph are wrong/missing, I hope this is not a part of the puzzle...

Comment: Edited out the LOL FLIRT words. They were from a previous question I was using as a template. And no the links should work. That's probably another mistake from the template.

Comment: Just fixed up your links - you had accidentally deleted the link URLs from the bottom of the template, so the one marked up as "[1]" directed to your table image, while those marked as 2-4 had nothing to point to. All fixed now though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Plot Word™ is a word where

> if you take for each letter its two digit position in the alphabet (A=01, Z=26), and then plot those in a 2-dimensional graph at the point ($x$ = second digit, $y$ = first digit), you can draw a straight line through them.

Examples:

> fox → 06 15 24, which is a straight line ($y = 6 - x$)
>  may → 13 01 25, which yields $y = (x - 1) / 2$
>  spoon → 19 16 15 15 14, which yields $y = 1$

So either

> the word consists of letters in one of these groups: A-J, K-T, U-Z;
>  this is the case for: pork, beef, cage, spoon, face, hedge, room

or

> it contains at most one letter from each of the groups, and these are in an arithmetic progression, as found by Rand al'Thor;
>  (a letter may be used more than once)
>  this is the case for: fox, may, wall, cull, gun

Answer (score 0):

I think a Plot Word should be

> one in which all the letters used in the word form an arithmetic progression through the alphabet.

For example, FOX and MAY and WALL

> use letters $6,15,24$ and $1,13,25$ and $1,12,23$ respectively.

This also fits with the hints, and it seems to be a quite specific thing that fits. However,

> it doesn't seem to work with all of the words: e.g. PORK is $11,15,16,18$ and FACE is $1,3,5,6$ (although CAGE does work with $1,3,5,7$). Is there a mistake in the puzzle, or is something different going on with the four-distinct-letter words?

Comment: What you've discovered.... Is a property of some Plot Words™, but that's not what plot words are.